# How change the y-axis numbers to be horizontal on an NMDS plot created in vegan?

Tags: plot, vegan

Can I change the y-axis numbers to be horizontal on an NMDS plot created in vegan?

```
library(vegan)
sp <- poop[,28:34]
bat <- poop[,4:7] 
mds1 <- metaMDS(sp, k=3,try=200)

plot(mds1$points[,1], mds1$points[,2], pch = as.numeric(bat$species),
 col= as.numeric(bat$species),
 xlab = "NMDS1", ylab= "NMDS2")
```

[image: NMDS plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **R**, the direction of labels is controlled by graphical parameter  `las` (see `?par`). You can also give this parameter in `plot` call for the `metaMDS` result. As you see from `?par`, `las=1` will put all labels horizontal.

More seriously, you should **not** plot `metaMDS` results like you do. It is better to use the dedicated `plot` method for the result, or if you want to do it all by yourself, you should at least force equal aspect ratio for axes with `asp = 1` in your `plot` call. So the following should work:

```
## with metaMDS plot:
plot(mds1, display="si", las=1, type = "n") # for an empty plot
points(mds1, pch = as.numeric(bat$species), col= as.numeric(bat$species))
## or with generic plot:
plot(mds1$points[,1], mds1$points[,2], pch = as.numeric(bat$species),
col= as.numeric(bat$species),
xlab = "NMDS1", ylab= "NMDS2",
asp = 1, las = 1) # this is new
```